# Парсинг сайта. Python

Tags: html, python, xpath, lxml

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно распарсить все странички со статьями на [этом](http://worldagnetwork.com) сайте. С парсингом отдельных страничек проблем не возникает. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как добраться до всех статей на сайте?
На сколько я понимаю, это нужно делать через относительные ссылки и xpath, но в коде я не нашел относительных ссылок на статьи.

[Вот](http://worldagnetwork.com/pharmaceuticals-agriculture/) пример статьи (первая статья в разделе Technology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут все просто.
Каждая страница со статьями это http://worldagnetwork.com/category/technology/page/<номер страницы>/
Боюсь что его придется вводить ручками так как к сожалению количество страниц не указано на странице.
Инкрименируйте пока не начнет возвращать 404)
Распарсивая каждую страницу вы можете получить все ссылки на странице, а затем парсите страницы по ссылкам. Все.

Comment: Дайте, пожалуйста, как пример, ссылку на статью, которую я указал в вопросе.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос... У Вас есть ссылка на статью. Вы ее указали. Что именно вы хотите получить?

Comment: Я не совсем понял, где брать номер страницы.

Comment: Получаете текст из всех a.page-numbers и находите самый большой int это количество страниц.

Comment: Смотрите, в ответе Вы написали, что каждая страница со статьями - это http://worldagnetwork.com/category/technology/page/<номер страницы>/ . Не могли бы Вы дать ссылку в таком же виде на ту страницу, которую я указал в вопросе, чтобы у меня был пример.

Comment: Нет нет все не много сложнее. Смотрите на примере.
Вначале вы парсите страницу
http://worldagnetwork.com/category/technology/page/<номер страницы>/
На ней получаете все ссылки на статьи. Распарсиваете эти ссылки, а а затем, переходите на слудующую страницу вида 
http://worldagnetwork.com/category/technology/page/<номер страницы>/

так понятнее?

Comment: Да, я понял, что Вы имели в виду. с помощью Вашего метода я буду получать абсолютные ссылки на каждую статью. Но я хотел бы узнать, как можно сделать это с помощь относительных ссылок и библиотеки lxml.

Comment: Библиотека тут совершенно не играет никакой роли. Это решаемо как на lxml так и на BS или на чем угодно еще. А относительных ссылок нет. И вообще какая разница полная ссылка или относительная? Если ставить вопрос так, то это не решаемо через относительные ссылки.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!